# Creating a binary output from MASM without header

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

When I write some code, which consists of position independent code and the first instruction would be at offset 0, so that I can simply load it into memory and jump to it. How can I create such a bin file using MASM, so that it doesn't have any header, only the data I put into the source file?

Something similar to the old COM programs I would think. But can I create a COM file and still use regular 32 bit instructions?

Comment: MSDOS COM programs assumed to be loaded always at address 100h

Comment: Yes, I know. this was just an example. Even so, if the entry point would be always at 100h I still would know where it is, without having to parsing some header, which was the point of my question. Though I prefere to have the entry point at 0 of course.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about MASM, but you could do it with NASM:

```
org 0
bits 32

; code goes here
```

Assemble with `nasm -f bin -o foo.bin foo.asm`